# Natbib: unsort but sort inside a merged citation?

Tags: natbib

I'm sorry if this was already asked. I cannot find a solution.

I am using natbib (`\usepackage[numbers, compress]{natbib}`) with `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` to sort by appearance.

This works, excepted that the result is not sorted when an "old" reference is cited again.

Exemple: If a first paragraph cites ref1, and a new paragraph cites: \cite{ref2, ref1, ref3, ref4, ref5}, I will get:

> Bla bla [1] \ Bla bla [2, 1, 3-5].

Is it possible to sort by appearance but still sort numerically the printed result?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the [natbib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) option `sort&compress`, not `compress`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% create a small bib file "on the fly":
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{r1, author="A", title="Ba", year=3001}
@misc{r2, author="B", title="Bb", year=3002}
@misc{r3, author="C", title="Bc", year=3003}
@misc{r4, author="D", title="Bd", year=3004}
@misc{r5, author="E", title="Be", year=3005}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\begin{document} 
\cite{r2}

\cite{r1,r2,r5,r3,r4}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ooh, that was easy thanks!   (Hint for others; for some reason, re-executing PDFLatex many times did not update the document. I had to delete all the previous latex-generated files first).